# Rendering Saturn's rings in 2D with python

Tags: python, rendering, pycairo

I am trying to create a program to automatically render planets and planetary rings. I want to use [pycairo](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo) since it seems light and easy (however I do take suggestions). I am having a hard time understanding how I would hide only part of the ring that surrounds the planet. I am looking into the ninth line of [this](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/blob/master/examples/pycairo_examples.ipynb) pycairo example.

[Here](https://2dgameartguru.com/making-the-rings-of-saturn/) is an example of what I envision (example is for inkscape).

My question is: How do I add rings that are tilted (similar to the aforementioned inkscape example) around the sphere depicted in the aforementioned pycairo example?